# How do I make a gateway entry on a network adapter in Windows 10 persist after reboots?

Tags: networking, windows-10, vpn, office365

I am using NordVPN on Windows 10 (both of them are up to date). One of the problems with having a continuous VPN connection is that Office 365 does not play well with it. The connection is fine for some time, and it then complains about not being able to connect to the network (Office 365 that is).

Now, NordVPN has a solution up for this and it works. It entails going into network settings for the VPN tunneling adapter that NordVPN installs, going to the IPv4 settings for that adapter and adding a default gateway entry that points to my home router. If I do this, everything is hunky dory and life is back to normal.

Only problem is that this entry disappears when my desktop powers down automatically after inactivity, or I reboot it for some reason. I need to go through the whole process again. It is not a very painful thing to do once in a while, but if you end up doing it multiple times a day, it starts to become a nuisance.

Any way I can make this entry persist? I did some Googling, but the only things that come up when I look for keywords are how to add persistent static routes on Windows 10 and that is not even close to what I am trying to do.

If anyone has any experience, please do let me know. I assume it would involve making some registry edits, scripting or such.

Comment: When you added the Gateway, did you uncheck Automatic Metric?

Comment: Another thing to try is to set up an association in your router (port settings) with the MAC address of the Desktop so that it always gets the same IP address. That may help it retain the Gateway address.

Comment: @John, the automatic metric box was unchecked anyway. I did not change that setting. Let me try the other option and see what happens. Will report back in a bit.

Comment: @John, the port association on the router did not work. My started my desktop up this morning, and I had to re-enter everything. I spoke to NordVPN support and they wanted me to reset the entire IP stack. Not sure if I want to do that at this point. Any advice?

Comment: Something I do not like doing, but you might try a static IP for your workstation.

Comment: @John, naive question for you. What would be the difference between a DHCP port association that ensures a devices receives the same IP address from the router every time and a static address assignment? Both of them accomplish the same thing, but at different points in the network, no?

Comment: Static IP addresses should be outside the DHCP range. And I suggest because you said IP / MAC association did not work for you.